# Fabric canvas free drawing inside a rotated div

Tags: angular, fabricjs

I have a fabric canvas within a container that is rotated by an angle - say 270deg in this example:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-canvas-q5zpey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcanvas.component.ts)

As I freehand draw the coords are off. I want to apply a transformation based on the rotation and store data in the backend without the rotation, so it remains correct even if rotation is not applied later.

How do I do this?

If the container is rotated, I expected the freehand drawing to get transformed based on the angle and work as expected